# dynamic value in one field in mysql DB

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I use laravel framework . I have two table. users and points . that has one to many relationship between them.in points table saved many records related to a one user that keep all of the ponits we assign to this user.I want to keep sum this points to one field as sumpoints filed in user table.how can i do it in laravel

Comment: You can do $user = User::with('points')->find($userId); $user->points->sum('columnName');

Comment: @IvanJelev I want to handle it dynamic database side.when add some records to points automatic  update  sumPoints field in users

Comment: If you want to do that, you should use simple method but not good - with ajax request and json data, for example request every 5 second. Or better solution but complex with websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in your Points model:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    self::created(function($model){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->sumfields = Points::where('user_id',$user->id)->sum('points');
        $user->save();
    });
}
```

The `self::created` function gets called **after** a new instance of that model has been created.

However if this was my project, I would probably do what Ivan Jelev suggested to you (doing the sum only when you need it).

Comment: The solution I found was using observer .When a point is created observer call creating method . computed sum points and update user

Comment: I would just like to point out that what I've done is essentially the same as using an observer, though using an observer will mean cleaner code. Glad you got it working.